# How to call two different API services (App engine) in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib3

I have two different App Engine services and I wanted to access the same from other different service. I just wanted to call the URL so that it can perform all the operations. When I ran in Jupyter notebook, below code worked. But when I am running in another app engine service, I am getting 502 bad gateway issue.

```
gatopubsub=urllib3.connection_from_url(r"url")
gatopubsub.request(method="GET",url=r"url")
time.sleep(120)
dataflow=urllib3.connection_from_url(r"url")
dataflow.request(method="GET",url=r"url")
time.sleep(720)
bigquery_success=big_query()
```

I gave time.sleep because, each URL takes the specified seconds to complete
I tried to install google-appengine package. But I am getting HTTP issue which is the reason I tried URLLIB3
Please assist

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the `google-cloud-pubsub` and `google-cloud-dataflow` client libraries instead of calling the APIs directly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. Thanks @Dustin for answering the query. The main problem is security issue. When the Pycharm or Jupyter runs locally, we have SSL enabled in our browser so that our code can access the App services. But in my case, SSL certificate is not uploaded in App Engine. So because of this, I couldnt access other services in a better way.